# Using Google Sheets example - doesn't display authorisation window or url

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to manipulate a Google Sheet from c#. I've followed the instructions given in the [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) page but, unlike others who have problems at the authorisation step, I'm simply not getting anything in the browser or the console.

According to the instructions, step 4...

"The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access:

The sample will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser."

I don't get anything at all in the browser. If it's closed it doesn't open and if it's open it doesn't change.  The console window is equally non-eventful.  After a few seconds the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() method times out with an error suggesting the request is not authorised, which is obviously correct!

Anyone else had a similar issue of the browser not opening with the auth. request?  I know that I could setup a service account and go that way, but this should work.

Thoughts, suggestions, please?

Comment: Additional info: Make sure that you have authorized your application properly. From this [doc](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing), it stated that when your application requests private data, the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data. While when your application requests public data, the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.

Comment: @abielita Thanks, I'll bear that in mind if the problem arises, but so far so good.  Such a stupid problem though, wasted a good few hours trawling the web for that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the simplest answers are sometimes the best.  I needed to run VS as Administrator to grant it enough privileges to open the necessary page, since I'm logged on as just a normal user.

All good now.